# How to shift group of elements in a matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to move selected group of elements in a matrix by some distance horizontally and vertically.

I'm using Java, as input I have:

- 2d array of elements
- array with coordinates of elements to move (array of `Point` objects)
- distance to move (as `Point` object, `Point.x` - horizontal shift, `Point.y` - vertical)

For example moving all the letters by 1 position to the right would look like this:

```
From:
A B 0 1
2 C 3 4
5 6 7 8

To:
0 A B 1
2 3 C 4
5 6 7 8
```

Another example, moving letters by 1 position horizontally and 1 vertically:

```
From:
A B 0 1
C D 2 3
4 5 6 7

To:
6 2 0 1
5 A B 3
4 C D 7
```

(note how numbers fill the created gap)

Moving elements for long distances was easy as there was no overlappings, but now I'm stuck on the examples above.

Another example (easy case, no overlapping). Moving same square by (2,2):

```
From:
A  B  0  1
C  D  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11

To:
6  7  0  1
10 11 2  3
4  5  A  B
8  9  C  D
```

Comment: Having two separate copies of the matrix -- one as a "source" and the other as a "destination" -- might help you avoid overlappings.

Comment: Aren't these just simple swaps? Am I missing something? Do the overlappings somehow make swaps not possible?

Comment: You can think of a rotating of values in a particular direction. e.g. on the diagonal A -> D -> 6 becomes 6 -> A -> D

Comment: @Nick difficulty comes not from the element swapping, but deciding which element swap with which one. For example in first example `[0,0] ` needs to be swapped with `[0,2]` (and not `[0,1]`)

Comment: I can understand whats happening in the first example, but I don't quite understand the second example. Why is 6 in the upper left corner exactly? Could you be more precise about the exchange rules.

Comment: @tigger The rules are that when replacement cells fill the created gap they stay more or less in the same formation as they were before (2 was above and to the right from 5, and still is). I can't formulate the rules precisely.

Comment: @serg I ask because in the first case its clear what is happening, you are just rotating the rows. So if you wanted to implement 1 pos horizontally and 1 vertically, you simply rotate the relevant rows and then the relevant columns (or vice versa). However in this methodology, 6 will not end up in the top left corner. I guess its hard to provide the correct algorithm without knowing the precise notion of what the rules are.

Comment: @tigger So then 0 would be in the corner? That would be bad, as that cell shouldn't be touched at all during this move. I would rather agree to random locations for 6,2,5 inside that gap.

Comment: @serg, Ahh, I see what you are saying. So its essentially an immediate swap, without those intermediary steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something out, that actually works when the array with the Point objects (that need to be moved) is  *sorted descending*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // first an example matrix with chars to fit your example
    char[][] matrix = new char[3][];
    matrix[0] = new char[]{'A', 'B', '0', '1'};
    matrix[1] = new char[]{'C', 'D', '2', '3'};
    matrix[2] = new char[]{'4', '5', '6', '7'};

    // then the elements you want to move (the highest index first!)
    Point[] elements = new Point[]{
        new Point(1, 1),
        new Point(1, 0),
        new Point(0, 1),
        new Point(0, 0)
    };

    // the direction indicates with where the element has to go to from it's current index. So (1,1) means one right, one down
    Point directionPoint = new Point(1, 1);
    // print the matrix to see what the original looks like
    printMatrix(matrix);

    // iterate through the elements that have to be moved
    for (Point p : elements) {
        move(p, directionPoint, matrix);
        printMatrix(matrix); 
    }
}

// this method takes one element, the direction and the matrix and moves this one element by switching it with the element that is at its destination index
public static void move(Point elementToMove, Point direction, char[][] matrix) {
    char temp = matrix[elementToMove.x][elementToMove.y];
    matrix[elementToMove.x][elementToMove.y] = matrix[elementToMove.x + direction.x][elementToMove.y + direction.y];
    matrix[elementToMove.x + direction.x][elementToMove.y + direction.y] = temp;
}

// just a simple print method to see the current matrix
public static void printMatrix(char[][] matrix) {
    for (char[] row : matrix) {
        String line = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            line += row[i] + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
}
```

And when I run it, this is the result (the first matrix is the original, the last matrix is the result):

```
A B 0 1 
C D 2 3 
4 5 6 7 
---
A B 0 1 
C 6 2 3 
4 5 D 7 
---
A B 0 1 
5 6 2 3 
4 C D 7 
---
A 2 0 1 
5 6 B 3 
4 C D 7 
---
6 2 0 1 
5 A B 3 
4 C D 7
```

Now I know this may not be the most elegant solution and I am almost certain, it is not complete for all possible cases, but it shows, that "shifting" works, when the elements are ordered. You just have to start shifting with the last element (when you want to shift to the right). If of course you want to shift to the left (maybe `direction=(0,-1)`) you need to begin with the first element... and so on

Answer (score 1):

Just make a copy of your matrix.

let a = your original matrix

let b = your destination matrix

Before a move, let b = a;

If you want to move a[i][j] to a[p][q] just move a[i][j] to b[p][q] at first.

We should decide what numbers to fill the gap then:

```
For every cell(i,j):

Step 1. Check if the cell will be a gap after the move, if not do nothing.

Step 2. find where the cell moves(denotes by (x,y)).

Step 3. If (x,y) is not a number before the move then repeat Step 2, 
        else we can say after the move b[i][j] is a[x][y].
```

And after the move is done, just copy array b to array a and do next move.